# Git diff-tree does not show up anything on a merge

Tags: git, gitlab

I am using the below command in my CI pipeline to determine the list of files changed as part of the given commit id.

```
git diff-tree --no-commit-id --name-only -r 243cb97da650f71b991b2d9927a3d66e94400e30
```

This works fine when we do a git push to the branch.
But when we complete a merge request from another branch to the same branch, a new commit id is generated and when I submit the same query, it does not give any results.
git diff-tree --no-commit-id --name-only -r newcommitid
But if I go to Gitlab UI in the same branch, when I select the new commit id, I can see the changed files. How is the git lab UI works in this specific case? Whats the alternate git command I can use to list the changed files?

Comment: If you compare your commit with it's first parent, then you should get what you want for both a commit with one parent, and a commit with 2 or more parents (a merge commit).

Comment: Note that `git diff-tree` requires `-m`, `-c`, or `--cc` when given just a single hash ID of a merge commit. Its default is to show no diff at all for merges. (Compare with `git show`, whose default is `--cc`.) Regular `git diff` is somewhat different as it does not allow you to supply just the one hash ID here.

Comment: Thanks TTK and @torek , I tried the option suggested by latter and it worked.

Comment: Beware of combined commits: combined commits *omit* some diffs on purpose.